# Joomla tooltip not hiding

Tags: tooltip, joomla2.5

My problem is that tooltips are not hiding after the cursor is moved away from the text with tooltip. You can check this page for an example of this problem:
http://federationgenealogie.qc.ca/nous-contacter (which is an simple com_contacts page)

But the problem persists throughout the website.

I've tried to the a template override of the com_contacts and to change the way tool-tips are handled using: http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_add_tooltips_to_your_Joomla!_website

```
$toolTipArray = array('className' => 'mytooltipclass', 'showDelay'=>'500', 
'hideDelay'=>'500', 'fixed'=>true,
 'onShow'=>"function(tip) {tip.effect('opacity', 
  {duration: 500, wait: false}).start(0,1)}", 
'onHide'=>"function(tip) {tip.effect('opacity', 
  {duration: 500, wait: false}).start(1,0)}");
JHTML::_('behavior.tooltip', '.hasTip', $toolTipArray); ?>
```

Only the `'fixed'=>true` parameter works, so I get a feeling this kind of works. But since all other parameters are not working, this is not a solution.

I've also tried to make my own tooltip.js file containing:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
       //do your tips stuff in here...
       var zoomTip = new Tips($$('.hasTip'), {
          className: 'mytooltipclass', //this is the prefix for the CSS class
          offsets: {
                    'x': 20,       //default is 16
                    'y': 30        //default is 16
          },
          initialize:function(){
             this.fx = new Fx.Style(this.toolTip, 'opacity', 
                             {duration: 1000, wait: false}).set(0);
          },
          onShow: function(toolTip) {
             this.fx.start(0,.8);
          },
          onHide: function(toolTip) {
             this.fx.start(.8,0);
          }
       });
    });
```

But I only get a tooltip that looks like an html alt, and changing my css files with according class names does not work.

Using a tooltip extension is not the solution because I need the default registration and contact page of joomla to work. And they both use `class="hasTip"`and changing this would require me to do some hacking which I can not do for durability reasons.

Using firebug and chrome, it does not seems like there is a conflict between javascripts.

Any ideas?